# What data generation process corresponds to exponential moving average prediction?

Tags: time-series, forecasting, arima, exponential-smoothing

For each ARMA process formulation, there is an optimal prediction. E.g.:

- When you believe that $y_{t+1}=\alpha y_t + \varepsilon_{t+1}$, where $\varepsilon_{t+1}$ are IID, you predict $\hat{y}_{t+1}=\alpha y_t$.
- When you believe that $y_{t+1}=\beta \varepsilon_{t} + \varepsilon_{t+1}$, where $\varepsilon_{t+1}$ are IID, you predict $\hat{y}_{t+1}=\beta y_t - \beta^2 y_{t-1} + \beta^3 y_{t-2}-\beta^4 y_{t-3}+...$.

The question is:

For which data generating process (except the obvious AR($\infty$)), the exponentially-moving-average forecast $\hat{y}_{t+1}=\alpha\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}(1-\alpha)^iy_{t-i}$ is optimal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you mean 
$$\hat{y}_{t+1} = \alpha \sum_{i=0}^\infty (1-\alpha)^i y_{t-i}.$$
That is the optimal prediction for several models, as explained in [Chatfield et al (JRSSD 2001)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1111/1467-9884.00267). The best known of these models are the ARIMA(0,1,1) process where the moving average parameter $\theta=1-\alpha$ and the ETS(A,N,N) and ETS(M,N,N) models. See http://otexts.org/fpp2/sec-7-ETS.html for details.